# Quitar segundos de mi consulta SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, transact-sql

Al ejecutar mi Script en la tabla `CheckInOut`:

```
select replace (convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + 
replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':','') as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

Me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo quisiera que no me muestre los segundos de la hora en mi reporte así.

010220200037

010220200819

010220200838

............

sucesivamente, sin segundos.

Comment: hola elert y si utilizas año mes dia por columna usando las mismas funciones year month day  select YEAR(FechaCompleta) as año, MONTH(FechaCompleta) as mes, DAY(FechaCompleta) as dia,
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'

Answer (score 2):

Por qué no cambiar `REPLACE` y `CONVERT` por `FORMAT`

```
select FORMAT(FechaCompleta, 'ddMMyyyyHHmm') as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

Comment: no sale en formato 24hrs el tiempo, pero igual gracias por el aporte amigo

Comment: cambiando las `hh` por `HH` (mayúsculas) y listo, tienes tu formato de 24 hrs

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la correción.

Answer (score 1):

como veo que el resultado de tu consulta tiene la cantidad de caracteres fijos (14), podrías utilizar la función SUBSTRING para obtener los 12 primeros caracteres y así obviar los últimos 2 caracteres que corresponden a los segundos, entonces:

```
select substring(replace (convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + 
replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''),1,12) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

Espero te ayude!

Comment: esta perfecto, gracias estimado

Answer (score 0):

Como el tamaño del campo es un varchar constante (día, mes, año, horas, minutos) tienes un total de 12 caracteres. Puedes aplicarle un `LEFT` o bien un `SUBSTRING` al resultado, quedándote con los 12 primeros caracteres.

Por ejemplo

```
select SUBSTRING(replace(convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + 
replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''), 1, 12) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

o bien

```
select LEFT(replace(convert(varchar, FechaCompleta,103),'/','') + 
replace(convert(varchar,FechaCompleta,108),':',''), 12) as DATE_FORMAT_STRING 
FROM [dbo].[CheckInOut] WHERE YEAR(FechaCompleta)='2020' AND MONTH(FechaCompleta) = '02'
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfecto con ambos,